# Confirmation needed for the proper definition of a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

My teacher taught us that a square matrix is called a diagonal matrix only if all the entries besides the ones on the principal diagonal are zero.

He further cautioned that there is no restriction on the entries of the principal diagonal and that they may be zero or non-zero, BUT there must be atleast one entry on the principal diagonal that is non-zero.

We were specifically told that null matrix is not a diagonal matrix as there simply is no entry along the diagonal.

However, most if not all sources on the internet say that null matrix is also a diagonal matrix as all the non-principal diagonal entries are zero.

Which one of the above definitions is correct?

Comment: I don't find reason to exclude the zero matrix as diagonal nor have I ever seen that. However, one is free to define it that way if one wants.

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonal

Comment: Technically, definitions can't be correct or wrong. However, the definition you saw in class is very non standard. The zero matrix is usually considered diagonal.

Comment: @GiulioR So it does not matter that the diagonal does not have any entries?

Comment: @Mark So it does not matter that the diagonal does not have any entries?

Comment: @Obinna Well, in your course you probably should use the definition you saw there. But outside of the course, better to use the standard definition, which includes the zero matrix.

Comment: The usual definition of diagonal does not exclude the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The null or zero matrix is just as uninteresting as it is important. This does not answer your question yet, but it paves the way towards the "correct" in the sense of most appropriate definition, which is outlined in your first sentence.

You should stick to it, and only to this one without adding further exceptions.

One reason is that diagonal matrices are a subset of the set of square matrices (of a fixed size) which carries an algebra structure, based on matrix multiplication. And to turn the subset of diagonal matrices into a subalgebra the zero or null matrix is indispensable.